# Creating a function that determines the impact of an outlier

Tags: r, function

My big-picture goal is to demonstrate the difference outliers can have on a dataset's average. I'm trying to create a function that uses the size of an outlier "k" as an input and outputs the average. Basically, the function needs to take any value "k" (which is the outlier) and return the average of vector x if the first value of x were replaced with k. For example, say the dataset is the heights of a population of students. The first value is supposed to be 71.3 cm but the kid accidentally put 713 cm. In this case, I want my function to tell me what would be the average of my vector if there was an outlier of value 713 (k = 713). So far I have the following, where x is the name of the dataset of heights.

```
average_err <- function(k) {
x[1] <- k
mean(x[1])
}
```

Then calculate the average if there was an outlier of 713

```
average_err(713)
```

However, my output is always identical to my input. Will someone please help me?

Comment: You are taking the mean of a single value `x[1]` not `x`.  Also you should be passing `x` and `k` to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
average_err <- function(x,k) {
mean(c(x,k))
}
```

In the above, instead of replacing one of the x-values with an outlier, you're adding an outlier to the existing x-vactor.  As @SteveM suggested, you should also have the function take x as an argument

```
x <- rnorm(25)
average_err(x, 100)
# [1] 3.627824
```

You could also build it to print both the mean of the original x, x with k and the difference:

```
average_err <- function(x,k) {
  m1 <- mean(x)
  m2 <- mean(c(x,k))
  d <- m2-m1
  out <- data.frame(mean = c(m1, m2, d))
  rownames(out) = c("x", "x,k", "difference")
  out
}
average_err(x,100)
#                  mean
# x          -0.2270631
# x,k         3.6278239
# difference  3.8548870
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand well, but I would rather replace "mean(x[1])" with "mean(x)" in your case. If you write mean(x[1]), you will do the average of one value only, the one you have replace with the outlier k.

```r
average_err <- function(k) {
x[1] <- k
mean(x)
}
```